# Making a content div fill the space between a variable height header and fixed height footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, variables, height

I've been trying to get a site layout working properly for quite some time now, and while many of my problems were solved by using the [Responsive Grid System](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) One mystery has yet to be solved.

The whole page will not have any scrolling and be a single page on the window. It's essentially a splash page with a large menu, so 100% of the page height and width will be everything visible in the window.

I have a header with a max-height of 108px and a max length of 800px. When the width of the window is less than 800px, the whole banner will resize to fit, making the height essentially variable.

I also have a footer, fixed at the bottom of the page, with a fixed height of 100px (may change depending on my needs). I intend for this to contain social media buttons and contact info, which won't need to scale at all.

So the issue now is figuring out how to make the middle content fill the gap between them. The content area will be filled in completely with 4 columns containing only background images and a little text. I did find [one solution using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665476/how-can-i-make-a-div-auto-adjust-its-height-between-two-divs-according-to-windo) but it doesn't seem to be working. I don't really know jquery all that well so I'm probably just not replacing everything I need to.

Here's what I got (images kept to help with context):

```js
var minHeight = 300px; // Define a minimum height for the middle div

var resizeMiddle = function() {
    var h = $('html').height() - $('.section header').height() - $('.section footer').height();
 h = h > minHeight ? h : minHeight;
 $('.section content').height(h);
}

$(document).ready(resizeMiddle);
$(window).resize(resizeMiddle);
```

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
 background-image: url('http://server.dewcraft.com/doodleplex/storage/themes/KokenTheme/inc/BG.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/*  SECTIONS  */
.section header {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
.section content{
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
}
.section footer {
 clear: both;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0% 0 0% 0%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }


/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
}
.group:after {
 clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}
                                               
     
/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4banner {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.span_4_of_4footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute; 
 bottom: 0;
}
.banner {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 800px;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.span_1_of_4draw {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 background-attachment: local; 
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8624213/ScrewAttack8WPS.png");
}
.span_1_of_4graph {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 background-attachment: local; 
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8624213/ScrewAttack8WPS.png");
}
.span_1_of_4pix {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 background-attachment: local; 
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8624213/ScrewAttack8WPS.png");
}
.span_1_of_4ani {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 background-attachment: local; 
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8624213/ScrewAttack8WPS.png");
}
footer {
 width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    display: table-row;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <script src="/doodleplex/storage/themes/RonTheme/inc/jquery.bgswitcher.js"></script>
 <body>
 <div class="section header group">
  <div class="col span_4_of_4banner">
   <img class="banner" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8624213/ronochromaticBannerS.png"/>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="section content group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_4draw">
  1 of 4 draw
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_4graph">
  1 of 4 graphics
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_4pix">
  1 of 4 pixelwork
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_4ani">
  1 of 4 animation
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="section footer group">
  <div class="col span_4_of_4footer">
   {{ site.copyright }}
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks relevant: http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you description of the site, you should be able to use position absolute or fixed and top/bottom to handle this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xn4hzhts/

Notice the overflow on the content. Allows it to be scrollable (so the content can go "underneath" the top and bottom).

```
<div class="top">This is your nav bar/header</div>
<div class="content">Put your pages' stuff here</div>
<div class="bottom">This is your footer</div>

.top
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0em;
    left: 0em;
    right: 0em;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4em;
    bottom: 4em;
    left: 0em;
    right: 0em;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.bottom
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0em;
    left: 0em;
    right: 0em;
    height: 4em;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I don't want the middle content to scroll at all. It's just a splash page, so everything will just be as is on the screen. The other issue with your solution is that the header div has a defined height, not a variable one. If it were all defined I could use this method, but because the height of the header will vary when the page width is below 800px, I can't use a defined top margin on the content div.

Comment: @Ronochromatic two things: 1. remove the overflow-y if you don't want it to scroll. 2. use media queries to make different heights for the different widths

Comment: Well I was hoping to avoid having to make multiple versions of my site, but I guess it's inevidable anyway. Besides, the columns would get pretty thin at 800px anyway. It's not what I wanted but I guess it's the next best thing. Now I just need to figure out how to make that work.

Comment: It took a while but I got it to work. I was hoping I could just adapt it to the responsive grid system I had but I guess they somehow conflicted so I just used your code and added a single responsive grid in the content. Works great! Thanks a ton!